# Hive Error : Unsupported language features in query in Spark execution

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Spark SQL Hive error for NOT EXISTS clause in sql query.**

```
Platform : cdh5.6.0

Hive version: Hive 1.1.0
```

The below NOT EXISTS query is running fine in hive prompt:
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM interim_t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a FROM xyz_n ABC where (a=a) AND (b=b) AND (c=c)

But the same program is giving error "Unsupported language features in query" in spark execution.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()


from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO abc_p PARTITION (SRVC_TYPE_CD='1') SELECT a,b,c,d FROM interim_t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a FROM xyz_n ABC where (a=a) AND (b=b) AND (c=c)")
```

Execution:

```
spark-submit --verbose --deploy-mode client /data/abc.py
```

Error message:

> **Unsupported language features in query**: INSERT INTO abc_p PARTITION
>   (SRVC_TYPE_CD='1') SELECT a,b,c,d FROM interim_t WHERE NOT EXISTS
>   (SELECT a FROM xyz_n ABC where (a=a) AND (b=b) AND (c=c))

I think sqlContext.sql is not supporting NOT EXISTS in hive queries. Could you please suggest some solution/alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below on pyspark shell, executed just fine with no errors.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table1 i WHERE  NOT EXISTS  (SELECT a FROM table2 x where i.a=x.a AND i.b=x.b AND i.c=x.c)");
```

I have following content in test.py

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table1 i WHERE  NOT EXISTS  (SELECT a FROM table2 x where i.a=x.a AND i.b=x.b AND i.c=x.c)");
```

Executed the script

```
spark-submit --verbose --deploy-mode client test.py
```

Executed successfully. can you give a try ?

My set up Hive 2.1.0 and Spark 2.0.2

I suspect your hive version is the issue

Comment: Yes, it could be the issue with Hive version and Spark version. I am using Platform : cdh5.6.0
Hive version: Hive 1.1.0                                                                      Spark Version: 1.6.                                                                                          For me also when i am executing the query on Hive prompt it is working but in spark program it is giving error.

Comment: yes try to upgrade hive version and give it a try. i made some changes to sql, above code should work

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, below solution worked for me. Put these lines in your file and test:-

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT a,b,c,d FROM interim_t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a FROM xyz_n ABC where (a=a) AND (b=b) AND (c=c)")
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("SRVC_TYPE_CD").saveAsTable("abc_p")
```

Apart from this you can try some more options like `mode` can be `append`. You can choose format for saving too. Like `mode("xxx").format("parquet")`. Format can be `parquet, orc` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for  Platform : cdh5.6.0 Hive version: Hive 1.1.0 The error is same "pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:
Unsupported language features in query:"  It doesn't support NOT EXISTS.